# YouTubePlayerSupportFragment No views can be added on top of the player

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I am struggle with `YouTubePlayerSupportFragment` for 3 days tried to make it run in a swipe fragment. It's show this error now, I have tried others ways and get `NullPointerException`. Is there a possible way to put `YouTubePlayerSupportFragment` in a swipe Fragment?

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No views can be added on top
>   of the player
>                                                                                            at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView.a(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                                                            at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView.addView(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1083)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:164)
>                                                                                            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1177)
>                                                                                            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1025)
>                                                                                            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1545)
>                                                                                            at android.view.View.measure(View.java)
>                                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java)
>                                                                                            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java)
>                                                                                            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout.onMeasure(AppBarLayout.java:199)
>                                                                                            at android.view.View.measure(View.java)
>                                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:668)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:735)
>                                                                                            at android.view.View.measure(View.java)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1075)
>                                                                                            at android.view.View.measure(View.java)
>                                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java)
>                                                                                            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
>                                                                                            at android.view.View.measure(View.java)
>                                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java)
>                                                                                            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java)
>                                                                                            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java)
>                                                                                            at android.view.View.measure(View.java)
>                                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java)
>                                                                                            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java)
>                                                                                            at android.view.View.measure(View.java)
>                                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java)
>                                                                                            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java)
>                                                                                            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java)
>                                                                                            at android.view.View.measure(View.java)
>                                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java)
>                                                                                            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java)
>                                                                                            at
>   com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java)
>                                                                                            at android.view.View.measure(View.java)
>                                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java)
>                                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java)
>                                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java)
>                                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java)
>                                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java)
>                                                                                            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java)
>                                                                                            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java)
>                                                                                            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java)
>                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java)
>                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
>                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
>                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

**MainActivity.java:**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 1"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 2"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 3"));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter
                (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });



        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**PagerAdapter.java:**

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter  {
    int mNumOfTabs;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                TabFragment1 tab1 = new TabFragment1();
                return tab1;
            case 1:
                TabFragment2 tab2 = new TabFragment2();
                return tab2;
            case 2:
                TabFragment3 tab3 = new TabFragment3();
                return tab3;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mNumOfTabs;
    }
}
```

**TabFragment1.java:**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment;

public class TabFragment1 extends Fragment  {
    private String currentVideoID = "nCgQDjiotG0";
    public static final String API_KEY = "XXX";
    private YouTubePlayer YPlayer;




    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fragment_1, container, false);

        YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youTubePlayerFragment = YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.newInstance();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.youTubePlayer, youTubePlayerFragment).commit();

        youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(API_KEY, new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider arg0, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
                if (!b) {
                    YPlayer = youTubePlayer;
                    YPlayer.setFullscreen(true);
                    YPlayer.loadVideo("2zNSgSzhBfM");
                    YPlayer.play();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider arg0, YouTubeInitializationResult arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
```

**tab_fragment_1.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment
        android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment"
        android:id="@+id/youTubePlayer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
transaction.replace(R.id.youTubePlayer, youTubePlayerFragment).commit();
```

in your `onCreateView` or simply retrieve the fragment directly (you have it in your layout) using

```
YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youTubePlayerFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.youTubePlayer);
```

Comment: Thank you!, it's work but I run into another error here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37604918/exception-thrown-by-invoked-constructor-in-com-google-android-youtube-api-jar-cl

Answer (score 9):

First instead of

```
   <fragment
      android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment"
        android:id="@+id/youTubePlayer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

use FrameLayout

```
 <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"></FrameLayout>
```

then after the initialize use

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.frame_fragment, youTubePlayerFragment);
        transaction.commit();
```