# Exception thrown by invoked constructor in com.google.android.youtube.api.jar.client.RemoteEmbeddedPlayer

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I have changed my dependencies to import com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1 and com.android.support:design:23.0.1 but it's not fix the error. The youtube Fragment show: "an Error occured while initializing the Youtube player"

> E/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI: Error creating YouTubePlayerView
>                                                                                                 com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.w$a: Exception thrown by
>   invoked constructor in
>   com.google.android.youtube.api.jar.client.RemoteEmbeddedPlayer
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.w.a(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.w.a(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.w.a(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.ac.a(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView.a(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView$1.a(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r.g(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$c.a(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$b.a(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                                     at
>   com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$a.handleMessage(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
>                                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
>                                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                                     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
>                                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
>                                                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>                                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.w.a(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.w.a(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.w.a(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.ac.a(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView.a(Unknown
>   Source) 
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView$1.a(Unknown
>   Source) 
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r.g(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$c.a(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$b.a(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                                                     at
>   com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$a.handleMessage(Unknown
>   Source) 
>                                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java) 
>                                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java) 
>                                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                                     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java) 
>                                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java) 
>                                                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The concrete class
>   implementing IObjectWrapper must have exactly *one* declared private
>   field for the wrapped object.  Preferably, this is an instance of the
>   ObjectWrapper class.
>                                                                                                     at vmh.a(SourceFile:76)
>                                                                                                     at
>   com.google.android.youtube.api.jar.client.RemoteEmbeddedPlayer.(SourceFile:147)
>                                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.w.a(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.w.a(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.w.a(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.ac.a(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView.a(Unknown
>   Source) 
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView$1.a(Unknown
>   Source) 
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r.g(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$c.a(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$b.a(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                                                     at
>   com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$a.handleMessage(Unknown
>   Source) 
>                                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java) 
>                                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java) 
>                                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                                     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java) 
>                                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)

Here is my build gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "vinchecks.wifi.info.karaokeviet2017"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile project(':YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi')
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 1"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 2"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 3"));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter
                (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });



        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

PagerAdapter.java

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter  {
    int mNumOfTabs;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                TabFragment1 tab1 = new TabFragment1();
                return tab1;
            case 1:
                TabFragment2 tab2 = new TabFragment2();
                return tab2;
            case 2:
                TabFragment3 tab3 = new TabFragment3();
                return tab3;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mNumOfTabs;
    }
}
```

TabFragment1.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment;

public class TabFragment1 extends Fragment  {
    private String currentVideoID = "nCgQDjiotG0";
    public static final String API_KEY = "XXX";
    private YouTubePlayer YPlayer;




    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View fragmentYoutubeView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fragment_1, container, false);

        YouTubePlayerSupportFragment  mYoutubePlayerFragment = new YouTubePlayerSupportFragment();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.youTubePlayer, mYoutubePlayerFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        mYoutubePlayerFragment.initialize(API_KEY, new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
                if(!wasRestored){
                    player.cueVideo("2zNSgSzhBfM");

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });

        return fragmentYoutubeView;

    }

}
```

tab_fragment_1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/youTubePlayer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:visibility="visible" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your build.gradle file, instead of
compile project(':YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi')

[replace it with] 
compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')

Make sure you have copied the jar file in to the libs folder.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
mYoutubePlayerFragment = YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.newInstance();
```

instead of

```
mYoutubePlayerFragment = new YouTubePlayerSupportFragment();
```

Comment: Yes, I have changed it to: YouTubePlayerSupportFragment  mYoutubePlayerFragment = new YouTubePlayerSupportFragment();